# Python 3, check if two elements in a row are uppercase

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, which are sometimes beginning with uppercase letters, sometimes not.
I want to check if words[I] begins with upper letter and the following one as well.

What I have right now is not working because the index of I+1 will always be out of range at the very last looping. How can I loop through the list and avoid this problem?

```py
words = ["Something", "anything","Marcus", "Söder","ist","Doof"]
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i][0].isupper() and words[i+1][0].isupper():
        print(words[I], words[I])
```

Comment: Change your loop to `for i in range(len(words) - 1):`

Comment: `for i in range(len(words) - 1):` is not pythonic and should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

We should check till the second-last element hence length - 1 will work fine.

```
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    if(words[i][0].isupper() and words[i+1][0].isupper()):
        #do anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subtract 1 from total length of list as you are doing 'i+1' in following loop.I hope this helps.

```
words = ["Something", "anything","Marcus", "Söder","ist","Doof"]
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    if words[i][0].isupper() and words[i+1][0].isupper():
        print(words[i], words[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example didn't have any double-uppercase, so I added "AA" as a trivial example.

You can avoid checking each letter twice by using groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ["Something", "anything","Marcus", "Söder","ist","Doof", "AA"]
for word in words:
    if any(is_up and len(list(grp)) > 1
           for is_up, grp in groupby(word, key=str.isupper)):
        print(word)
```

should give

```
AA
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `-` and do it like this:

```
words = ["Something", "anything","Marcus", "Söder","Ist","Doof"]

upr=[]

for i in range(len(words)-1):
    if words[i][0].isupper() and words[i+1][0].isupper():
        if words[i] not in upr and words[i+1] not in upr:
            upr.append(words[i])
            upr.append(words[i+1])

print(upr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
for i, j in zip(words, words[1:]):
   if i[0].isupper() and j[0].isupper():
      print(i,j)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `word[1:]` is a new list that starts with the second value.
2. `zip(words, words[1:])` is a iterator which returns a tuple with the `n` and `n+1` value from the list `words`. The first list is longer than the second but that does not matter in your case.

**Comment:**

1. `for i in range(len(words) - 1)` this is not pythonic (some might say blasphemous) and should be avoided.